# Custom multitouch in wpf/pixelsense

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, multi-touch, pixelsense

I'm working together with a PhD student that's doing a project regarding using computers for collaboration between people, specifically with touch. The platform for this is the pixelsense (surface) 2.0 table.

So far we've tried a few prototypes using the regular wpf/surface interface models and reached the conclusion that the multitouch capabilities aren't used to their full potential.

Therefor we'd like to implement custom multitouch gestures such that the amount of fingers and position relative to elements on the screen specifies the action. An example of such a gesture would be using 2 fingers, close to each other, from each hand to zoom instead of 2 fingers total. If this gesture was used instead of the normal pinch-to-zoom it would allow for both drawing and zooming on the same area.

While this approach has some problems that needs to solved we're having a more pressing problem implementing these custom gestures. We're aware it's possible to implement in XNA (by using TouchTarget.GetState) but it would be rather tedious to rewrite our interface so we'd rather avoid it.

So how would one go about implementing this in wpf/surface 2.0?

Comment: I believe all the needed info is in the MSDN docs and the surface developer guides...